# Copy Columns until a boundary

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Am trying tell VBA to copy all the cells from Column "Data_FirstCoumn" until "Data_Boundary" Column.

However VBA keeps throwing up an error stating that "AutoFill method of Range class failed".

Here's my code to provide context:

```
Sub Macro5()
Range("Data_FirstColumn").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Data_Boundary"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Columns("Data_First:Data_Boundary").Select
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Where are the ranges defined??

Comment: I have named two columns as "Data_FirstColumn" and "Data_Boundary" respectively. Also I want to autofill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub macro5()
    Range("A:A").Name = "Data_FirstColumn"
    Range("Z:Z").Name = "Data_Boundary"
    Range("Data_FirstColumn").Copy Range(Range("Data_FirstColumn"), Range("Data_Boundary"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [your error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209671.aspx) - you need the *destination* to **include the source**. Try:

`Range("Data_FirstColumn").AutoFill Destination:=Range("Data_FirstColumn:Data_Boundary"), Type:=xlFillDefault`